# Undoing effect of adding a Ubuntu-intended repository and updating on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, repository, node.js, ppa

### tl;dr

How do I fix this error on Debian

```
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_current.x nodistro Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

if the mistake was to run this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:agornostal/ulauncher -y && sudo apt update
```

which was intended for Ubuntu?

### Full story

I wanted to install [ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/#) on a Debian 11 machine, so I looked for the instruction *Ubuntu (Debian)* at the linked page, and run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe -y && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:agornostal/ulauncher -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install ulauncher
```

which failed, because that was for *Install via PPA (Ubuntu)*, which I hadn't read, as *Ubuntu (Debian)* above had tricked me into thinking the instructions were common (I'm normally a ArchLinux user, so I'm not that used anymore to installing stuff on Ubuntu or Debian).

The error was simply

```
Error: 'universe' invalid
```

so I tried executing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:agornostal/ulauncher -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install ulauncher
```

which failed with

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_current.x nodistro Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

That's when I read the instructions more carefully, discovering that on Debian I should have executed these commands

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y gnupg
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 0xfaf1020699503176
gpg --export 0xfaf1020699503176 | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/ulauncher-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ulauncher-archive-keyring.gpg] \
          http://ppa.launchpad.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu jammy main" \
          | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ulauncher-jammy.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ulauncher
```

so I tried that, but the error was still the same as above, so I understood I needed somehow to undo my first, intended-for-Ubuntu attempt. I tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:agornostal/ulauncher
```

so the first command from the Debian-specific instructions

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y gnupg
```

still errors, but a bit less:

```
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_current.x nodistro Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: hm, the "https://deb.nodesource.com/node_current.x" problem doesn't seem to stem from you setting up ulauncher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Marcus Müller says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760510/undoing-effect-of-adding-a-ubuntu-intended-repository-and-updating-on-debian#comment1450017_760510), the error you’re left with doesn’t seem to be related to your Ulauncher installation.

To fix the error, you can either:

- keep the Node.js repository, and add its key — follow [the Node.js instructions](https://deb.nodesource.com/):

  ```
  curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key |
  sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
  ```
- or remove the repository:

  ```
  rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
  ```

  (assuming the repository is defined in that file).

Comment: Not sure why, but the first approach didn't work, in the sense that `sudo apt update` would still fail after that `curl ...| sudo gpg...`, so I've gone for the second approach which succeeded. Should I be in need of installing Node.js, I hope I'll remember this answer. Thanks!